# dynamically register services in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, activator

I'm trying to dynamically register services in startup.cs.  I'm having trouble calling a method from the dynamically typed object.

## Steps

1. Create interface with method;

```
    public interface ICustBillTypeService
    { public static void RegisterTypeServices(IServiceCollection services) { } }
```

2. Create class from interface.  Method accepts a `ServiceCollection` and adds the appropriate `ServiceDescriptor`.

```
    public class RPT628Registration : ICustBillTypeService
    {
        public static void RegisterTypeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        { services.AddScoped<RPT628Service>();}
    }
```

3. Identify all classes in the assembly that implement the
   `ICustBillTypeService` and return the class name.

```
            var results = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => typeof(ICustBillEntityService).IsAssignableFrom(x) 
                        && !x.IsInterface 
                        && !x.IsAbstract)
                    .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

4. For each class found, call the interface method implemented by the class to add the service to the ServiceCollection
   *This is where I'm running into problems.  Step 3 returns the name of all the types that implement the interface.  I can step through each result, determine the type and create an instance of the type, but I can't get to the method of the class because my object is dynamically typed at runtime and only has access to the base object definition*

```
            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                Type resultType = Type.GetType(result);
                var t = Activator.CreateInstance(resultType);
    -->         t.RegisterTypeServices(services);  //fails the build because the method is not part of the object until run time.
            }
```

I'd prefer not to call the "string" name of the method.  Is there anyway to leverage the interface with "t" so I can call the method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this up, I figured it out.  It does require the method name to be passed in as a string, but I can live with that.

```
///  Add "GetTypeServices(services)" to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs;


        public void GetTypeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var results = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => typeof(ICustBillTypeService).IsAssignableFrom(x) 
                        && !x.IsInterface 
                        && !x.IsAbstract)
                    .Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();

            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                Type resultType = Type.GetType(result);
                MethodInfo typeMethod = resultType.GetMethod("RegisterTypeServices");                
                var t = Activator.CreateInstance(resultType);
                dynamic methodResult = typeMethod.Invoke(t, new object[] { services });                
            }
        }
```

Now Startup.cs does not have to be modified when we need to add a new service.  As long as the developer creates a new class inheriting the interface, it will be discovered automatically.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid hardcoding the method name string you could try using the nameof() operator which does give you the string but saves you from making it a literal in your code.